# How can I check a class has no arguments constructor

Tags: java, reflection

```
    Object obj = new Object();
    try {
        obj.getClass().getConstructor();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        dosomething();          
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I don't want check like this, because it throw a Exception.

Is there another way?

Comment: Why the exception-phobia?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can get all `Constructor`s and check their number of parameters, stopping when you find one that has 0.

```
private boolean hasParameterlessPublicConstructor(Class<?> clazz) {
    for (Constructor<?> constructor : clazz.getConstructors()) {
        // In Java 7-, use getParameterTypes and check the length of the array returned
        if (constructor.getParameterCount() == 0) { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You'd have to use `getDeclaredConstructors()` for non-public constructors.

Rewritten with `Stream`.

```
private boolean hasParameterlessConstructor(Class<?> clazz) {
    return Stream.of(clazz.getConstructors())
                 .anyMatch((c) -> c.getParameterCount() == 0);
}
```

Comment: Constructor class has no getParameterCount() method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html

Comment: @gerrytan [That's a new Java 8 method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#getParameterCount--). You can use `getParameterTypes` and check the size of the array returned.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using Spring you can use [ClassUtils.hasConstructor()](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/ClassUtils.html#hasConstructor-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Class...-):

```
ClassUtils.hasConstructor(obj.getClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method that loops the class's constructor and check if any has no-arg constructor.

```
boolean hasNoArgConstructor(Class<?> klass) {
  for(Constructor c : klass.getDeclaredConstructors()) {
    if(c.getParameterTypes().length == 0) return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Note that by using `getDeclaredConstructors()`, default constructor added by the compiler will be included. Eg following will return true

```
class A { }

hasNoArgConstructor(A.class);
```

You can use `getConstructors()` but it will only check visible constructors. Hence following will return false

```
boolean hasNoArgConstructor(Class<?> klass) {
  for(Constructor c : klass.getConstructors()) {
    if(c.getParameterTypes().length == 0) return true;
  }
  return false;
}

class B {
  private B() {}
}

hasNoArgConstructor(B.class);
```