# PHP - How can I check a class has no arguments constructor?

Tags: php, class, oop, arguments

In few worlds : I would like to do the [same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810634/how-can-i-check-a-class-has-no-arguments-constructor) but in PHP.

In details : I have a `Class A method` that instantiates a `Class X` which can be a `Class B or C`.

**Class A**

```
class A{

   ...
   protected function init(){
       if( !empty( $this->sub_pages ) ){
           foreach ( $this->sub_pages as $sub_page ){
                $class = $sub_page['class_path'];
                //Here, I need to check if ClassX ( = $class) constructor has arguments.
                if( no arguments){
                   new $class();
                }else{
                   new $class( $sub_page['data'] );
                }
           }
       }
   }

   ...

}
```

**Class B**

```
class B{
    public function __construct(){ //<-- No arguments

    }    
}
```

**Class C**

```
class C extends D{
    public function __construct( $data ){ //<-- With arguments
        parent::__construct( $data );
    }    
}
```

Someone know the answer ?

Comment: What's the point? what are you going to do when you come across a constructor that takes parameters?

Comment: You can find out if a class constructor has params but then how would you determine what param to pass there?

Comment: I change my code to see exactly what and where I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check whether a class has a constructor and if that constructor accepts any params or not then you can do it using `PHP`'s [Reflection Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) for example:

```
$reflector = new \ReflectionClass('SomeClass');

$constructor = $reflector->getConstructor();

if ($constructor && $constructor->getParameters()) {
    // Since your class needs $sub_page['data'] and
    // you already have this in your current scope
    $instance = $reflector->newInstanceArgs($sub_page['data']);
} else {
    $instance = new SomeClass;
}
```

Btw, If you have type hinted dependencies (like other class instance) then you can find out what is the dependency and can also new up that dependent class to pass as param.

Answer (score 0):

Base on @The Alpha answer, I found this :

```
class A{

   ...

   protected function init(){
       if( !empty( $this->sub_pages ) ){
           foreach ( $this->sub_pages as $sub_page ){
               try {
                   $reflector = new \ReflectionClass( $class );
                   if (!$constructor = $reflector->getConstructor()) {
                       printf( "The Class '%s' has not got a constructor", $class );                
                   }else {
                        // has a constructor
                        if ( $paramsArray = $constructor->getParameters() ) {
                            new $class( $sub_page['data'] );
                        }else{
                            new $class();
                        }
                    }
                } catch ( \ReflectionException $e ) {
                    echo $e;
                }

         }
     }

     ...

}
```